WebSocket connection to RPC failed
My node in paseo is up and running producing and finalizing block xcavate here but when I try to access wss://rpc-paseo.xcavate.io:443, it throw WebSocket connection to RPC failed error. Can anybody tell me what is wrong here?

the certificate is expired. That why the websocket fail to connect.
curl -v https://rpc-paseo.xcavate.io
*   Trying 18.200.173.18:443...
* Connected to rpc-paseo.xcavate.io (18.200.173.18) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
* Closing connection
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Thx!
